# Create List<int> from a list<class>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that is defined like this:

```
class A
{
 int contractID;
 string name;
 string blah;
 etc...
}
```

Multiple ClassA are stored  stored in List(). I and to create a List based off all the ContractID's in List. Is there a way in LINQ to be able to do this instead of iterating through List()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) extension method to create a projection of the contractID. Like:

```
var listOfClass = new List<ClassA>(); //Or however you get your list.
var contractIDs = listOfClass.Select(x => x.contractID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`var onlyContractIDs = myList.Select(x => x.contractID).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ClassA> input = ...;
List<int> output = input.Select(a => a.contractID).ToList();
```

`Select` is a generic method. Explicitly specified, it would be `Select<ClassA, int>`, specifying the input and output types.

The `ToList()` at the end converts from an `IEnumerable<int>` to a `List<int>`, and it does the iteration over the input list now, rather than when the `IEnumerable<int>` is enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a List you can make a List with LINQ like this

```
List<int> contractIDs = mycollection.Select(a => a.ContractID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<ClassA>();
...            
list.Select(a => a.ContractID);
```